# COUNTIF with a question mark symbol

Tags: google-sheets

I need to count the cells that contains the actual `?` symbol inside. How do I do a

`CountIF(range, "?")`

I tried `"\?"` but it returns 0.

Comment: I want to count cells that contains the symbol ?

Comment: try to put other symbol in the column they will be counted too, ? replaces any character

Comment: Thanks, solved, maybe add an answer so I can select it

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Even inside double quotes a search with `?` will return more than just cells fully occupied by a single question mark. To make the search more literal rather than, in part, have the question mark as a wild card, 'escape' it with a tilde (swung dash `~`), like so:

```
=countif(A:A,"~?")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working also in conditional formatting expressions.

Comment: @pnuts: what if i try to find some text which contains "?"?

Comment: Finding out that this was the problem was more of an issue, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

=countif(range,"asterisk~?asterisk") to include cells that have a ? by themselves or in addition to other text