# Google Sheets MATCH with search type '0' returning incorrect result

Tags: google-sheets, match

The MATCH function in google sheets seems to exhibit incorrect behaviour when dealing with cells that contain question marks.

As a minimal example, place a question mark in cell A1, and the following equation in cell C1: `=MATCH(A1,B1:B,0)`. This formula will result in a "1" so long as there is any non-empty cell in column B.

This is unexpected because the third parameter in the MATCH function is "search-type", and a search type of 0 is supposed to only look for exact matches. With this formula I would expect it to return a result of "N/A" so long as there is no cell in column B whose value is a question mark.

If cell A1 contains more than just a question mark, then this error does not always occur. However, if cell A1 is of the form "X ?" where X is a string, and there is some cell in column B whose value is of the form "X Y" (where Y is some non-empty string), then this error also occurs.

Does anyone know why this error occurs? And how I can avoid this error?

---

Edit: Since posting this question, I found this other question:

[COUNTIF with a question mark symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945584/countif-with-a-question-mark-symbol)

This seems to be a related problem. In the linked thread, the answer explains that formulae treat the question mark symbol as a wildcard, and so to use the literal question mark, you need to "escape" it via "~?". However, this solution can not work for me since this relies on knowing that the cells that you are trying to match contain a question mark.

I suppose this modifies my question into: is there a way to modify the match function to automatically stop it treating the question mark as a wildcard?

The naive approach would be just manually replace question marks in my cell values with "~?", but I really would prefer not to do this. Anyone have any better ideas?

---

Edit2: Another hacky solution I found is the following formula: `=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?", "~?"),B1:B,0)`. Is this the best I can hope for? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the [***xmatch***](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12406049?hl=en):

```
=xmatch(A1,B:B)
```

[image]